# ¿Cual seria la mejor forma de desarrollar estilos CSS3?

Tags: css3, patrones-de-diseño

yo siempre he diseñado mi codigo CSS3:

```
/*

Author : 3lmo

Date : 13/NOV/2017

*/




      body {

        margin:0;
        padding: 0;


       }

    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {


       font-family: arial;
       font-size:100%;
    }



    .contenedor {

        margin:0 auto;
        width:50%;
        text-align:justify;
    }

    .text-center{

        text-align:center;
        font-family: arial;

    }
```

y mi pregunta es cual es el mejor patron,metodo o diseño para desarrollar codigo CSS3(estilos), mas organizado o estandar en la W3 estuve buscando y no encontre nada parecido ?

Existe algo parecido asi en CSS3?

Comment: si ya sabes css aprende bootstrap es un framework para diseño de paginas web te ahorra tiempo y diseño.

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil bueno conozco CSS3 uno 50% , pero siempre me a gustado crear todo el estilo de CSS3 pero igualmente uso Bootstrap pero mi pregunta no se realiciona con el diseño de algun proyecto, sino como como estructurar codigo CSS3, por ejemplo yo uso Bootstrap pero si agrego codigo mio en otro archivo css me gustaria saber cual es el mejor manera para diseñar codigo css3.

Comment: Tal vez podrías pegar el salto a SCSS y usar el [patrón 7-1](https://sass-guidelin.es/es/#el-patron-7-1). Lo uso para proyectos grandes y me resulta sumamente práctico.

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas no se ajustan bien al formato del sitio, es bastante subjetiva y las diferentes respuestas pueden ser igualmente válidas.

Comment: El mejor estilo es aquel que sea mas legible para el resto de tu equipo o para ti mismo en el futuro, no existe una regla totalmente estricta para formatear tu codigo pero si es buena idea respetar el indentado y los brackets.